# Query with two laravel models and return result

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I have two models, `User` and `Post`

**User Model:**

```
 public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');

    }
```

**Post Model:**

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

In my controller I have a public function which has:

```
$users = User::orderBy('is_ban', 'desc')->paginate(10);
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

Which is working as expected.
I also have one column in users table `is_ban' It's of boolean type.

I am looking for a query which will return the following:

> Only get post which has been made by the user which has `is_ban=false`

Comment: Could you regard the relation methods code in both models?

Comment: @SaidbakR I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps i haven't understood you, but i hope it will help. You can add it to your Post model

```
    public function getBannedUsersPosts()
    {
        return self::whereIn('user_id', User::where('is_ban', 0)->pluck('id'))->get();
    }
```

Comment: If i want it in my controller, then it will be `$posts = Post::whereIn('user_id', User::where('is_ban', 0)->pluck('id'))->get();` ??

Comment: Awesome this worked !! BTW for this question the function name should be `getUnBannedUserPosts()` ;)

Comment: Yes, it should)) i thought you need posts of users who was banned))